# How to get base plan id from android billing client

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-billing, play-billing-library

I am getting product details (which is nothing but subscription plans offered) using [queryProductDetailsAsyc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingClient#queryProductDetailsAsync(com.android.billingclient.api.QueryProductDetailsParams,%20com.android.billingclient.api.ProductDetailsResponseListener)) API. It returns [productDetails](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails) which has all the base plans under a product. these base plans or subscriptionOffers [subscriptionOfferDetails](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails) are configured in google play console with all the information like price, duration, offertoken etc. I am getting all the information except the id of the base plan. This base plan id is what identifies the plans in our system.  Is there a way to get this id ?

Answer (score 1):

They added this function in billing version 5.1

```
ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails.getBasePlanId()
```

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes#5-1

Answer (score 0):

In order to identify the plans, you can use tags. Tags can uniquely identifiy an offer or the base plan.

Tags in the console can accept multiple values but it would be better to use one.